# Pango Markup on Expander Label

Tags: python, pygtk, pango

I have a project in Python 2.7 and PyGTK 2.24.

I have the following code in my project:

```
    expTSet = gtk.Expander()
    expTSet.set_use_markup(True)
    expTSet.set_label('<span font_family="serif" size="18" weight="bold">Teacher Settings</span>')
    settingFixed.put(expTSet, 30, 200)
    expTSet.show()
```

The expander itself appears, but the label does not. What am I doing wrong? How do I make the expander's label visible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pango font sizes are not in points (like HTML/CSS), but rather [thousandths of points](http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/pango-markup-language.html). So `size="18"` means your font size is 0.018 points, which is too small to read. Change it to `size="18000"` and it will work as intended.